# passing values from a for loop into another array

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, loops

I am retrieving values from a XML file and storing them into an array called `wordList` using Actionscript 3.

Say these are the values of wordList: bear, cat, dog, kite, chair

I need to then format the values and store them in an another array called `words` 
so that the array called words looks like this

```
words=[" bear", "cat", "dog", "kite", "chair"];
```

How can I wrap each value of the array in quotation marks and pass them to the array called words?

**MY CODE AT THE MOMENT**

```
function RetrieveWords(puzzleInput:XML):void {
    var wordList:XMLList = puzzleInput.Word.puzWord;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < wordList.length(); i++)
    {
        var wordElement:XML = wordList[i];
        pWord.push(wordElement);

        trace(pWord[i]);
    }

    trace("words");
    pWord.toString();
    trace(pWord);
}
```

trace(pWord[i]) lists the words like this
bear
cat
dog
kite
chair

***trace(pWord) lists the values as

bear,cat,dog,kite,chair

I need to wrap each value in quotes and pass it to the array called words so that it looks like this

words=["bear", "cat", "dog", "kite", "chair"]

Comment: So you actually want the values to contain the quote marks? Are you sure you don't just want the values to be of type `String`?

Comment: In your code block, there is no mention of the `words` array. There is a `pWord` array. What is that?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
wordList.push[i];
```

does not really seem correct to me. First, to push an item onto an array you should use parenthesise not square brackets like so:

```
wordList.push(i);
```

Second, are you sure you want to push `i` onto this array? `i` is your int counter for your `for loop`.

Third, is `wordList` the correct array you want to push onto? It seems `wordList` is is your `XMLList` not your array of words.

If want you want is to create an array of words based on the words in your xml, then you can do something like this:

```
var words:Array = new Array();
var wordList:XMLList = puzzleInput.Word.puzWord;                   
for (var i:int = 0; i < wordList.length(); i++)
{
    var wordElement:XML = wordList[i];
    words.push(wordElement);
    trace(words[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, resolved the issue. I am new to actionscript and it was merely an issue with making some of the variables public and using pWord as the array for the puzzles. Thanks for your help. I should have explained the problem better when I first posted